# Strrpos not working properly when URl exists

Tags: php

I try to do something when the url contains a certain string. But this only works if the file is not avalaible.

example:

```
if (strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/file/1.txt') !== false) { 
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');  
}
```

Result: Is only working (=return 403) when 1.txt is non-existent

Is there anybody out there who could clear my brain?

Thanks!

Comment: Typically the server (Apache, Nginx, IIS, etc.) will serve file if they exist on disk, and then a common, but not default, pattern is to pass 404s to one or more PHP files for further processing. This is how most modern CMSs work. In your case, you just need a server rule to deny that file. For instance, if this were Apache, you’d use an htaccess file.

Comment: Hey Chris,

thank you so much for your reply. Unfortunatly. we cannot set a server rule (restrict by hoster) or .htaccess (Nxginx). So I tried and created a way to to it on application level (wordpress).

I just need to block of some slugs due to secruity reasons and ddos. May you have any other idea to do it?

Comment: Okay, you are in a WordPress world, that helps to know. Without a doubt, server rules exist, that is how WordPress works. (You can actually use WP without them, and I do during dev, but no host worth paying for would do this.) It is actually very rare for a host to restrict this, too. Are you Apache or Nginx? The server _has_ the rule in place already that says “if the file exists, don’t even ask/tell WordPress about it”, so there is no WP/PHP way of handling this without modifying these rules.

Comment: If you are Nginx, those are usually more specific than Apache which is usually a more generic hosting platform. They should have a support request where you can ask for custom rule sets. Otherwise, you can use a reverse proxy like Cloudflare, or just change hosts. My company hosts on our own servers using Nginx and this is a very easy thing, although usually not too common. Why do these files exists in the first place, if I may ask? Can you just delete them or move them elsewhere? Or password protect them?

Comment: Its Nginx and the hoster do not allow to modify the server rules and do not allow to customize it by themselfes, too. Very uncool